# Need pauses - timing not working on iterating through text strings w/ d3/svg (piling up on each other)

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to use d3 to animate text using an svg text with d3 transitions. I have it working as desired for a single string.

I want to iterate through strings from an array of json objects.

I can do this as well.

All the painting and transitions work great. Problem is, they all happen at once, and appear piled up on each other, and all animate all at once.

I have tried putting them in a setTimeout() to get them to appear sequentially.

Still does not work.

for ( i in haikuStr ) {

```
if( i !=0 ){
 //Make it wait if an appropriate time it is not the first one
     setTimeout( function() {
     showText();
 }, 11000 * i );
} else {
     //if i=0, don't make folks wait
    showText();
}
```

}

The showText() function is the full create container -> finish transitions.

I use 11000 * i to ensure that >2 iterations have 11 additional seconds per i.

I have spent quite a bit of time reading and trying to figure out how to get the loop to pause before cycling through to paint the next line.

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

The un-timed example is here, if you wish to see the text jumble up:

http://www.mysalmagundi.com/js/svg-d3-no-timing.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)? Or some of the other introductory [D3 tutorials](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials), such as those by [Scott Murray](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/)? Or [Three Little Circles](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html), or [Working with Selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/)? I ask because your `showText` function is misusing data joins; it creates `text` elements for every element in the global `haikuStr` array:

```
var text = haikuContainer.selectAll("text")
    .data(haikuStr)
    .html(String)
  .enter().append("text");
```

And all your text elements are overlapping because you set them to have the same y-attribute:

```
var thisHaiku = text
    .attr("x", -800)
    .attr("y", 120)
```

(Also, that selection.html call is a no-op because the update selection is guaranteed to be empty, since you just created `haikuContainer` it is guaranteed to not have any descendant text elements. And `thisHaiku` is the same value as the var `text`, because when method chaining selection.attr and similar methods return the current selection; so there’s no reason to create a separate var. Also, you shouldn’t use a [for-in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over arrays.)

If you wait 11 seconds, you’ll see the second SVG appear, but because of your data join as described above, it has the same overlapping text content.

If you just want to show a single piece of text, then pass that string to your `showText` function (e.g., `showText("hello")`). Then, since you’re just creating individual elements, just [selection.append](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-append) them rather than using a data-join. You only need the data-join when you’re creating (or updating or removing) a *variable* number of elements based on data; in this case it looks like you’re trying to just create a single element.

Comment: Thank you! Back to the drawing board... I went through dashing, Visual.ly and aligned left's that I found. I do want them all to appear at the same y, sliding in and sliding out like a slide show.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept this answer with the checkmark if I’ve answered your question. Or please clarify your question if you still need help.

Comment: Hi -

I wish the question was answered, but I'm still slogging away. I read through the add'l links you provided, & cleaned the detritus from my code (revision at http://www.mysalmagundi.com/js/so-16879522-811.html). I was able to get it down to creating only 1 container & not creating the overlapped text, so some improvement! 

However, the 2nd string now never shows up in the container. Based on your Thinking in Joins, I tried removing the attached text at the end of the loop (text.exit().remove();), but the console gave me errors ("is not a function").

cont'd...

Comment: To clarify my question: 

There should be 1 string running through the container like a slideshow at the same coordinates. The 1st should slide in&out completely, then the second in its place. What I *want* it to do (again, from your Thinking in Joins;) is finish the transitions, loop to the next string, & replace the string & start the animation over again, reusing same container, w/ each iteration through the loop. 

Can SVG even do this given the requirement for the tickertape behavior (ie, same coordinates)? Should I be thinking instead about using HTML5 canvas or something else instead?